# Is there a word for "someone who can talk to anyone"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, synonyms

Trying to think of a word for a resume that would cover "being able to converse with almost anyone from having a general knowledge of many subjects". It wouldn't be articulate but I can't find anything similar.

Comment: How about "a good listener"?

Comment: Well, literally speaking, "polyglot".  But that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: *Gregarious and conversational across a wide range of social contexts* is probably how I would describe someone able to communicate with all sorts and social classes.

Comment: I think I would just leave it at "good communicator".

Comment: Just don't say "I'm a real schmoozer"! Not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

[Communicative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/communicative):

> - inclined to communicate readily; talkative.

[Eloquent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eloquent)   conveys the idea of being  able to talk effectively to a great variety  of people:

> - having or exercising the power of fluent, forceful, and appropriate speech:
>   an eloquent orator.

(TFD)

Comment: I dunno, I wouldn't think it prudent to call oneself *eloquent* in a résumé.

Comment: @Robusto But *eloquent so fits the description, if not the use. +1

Answer (score 2):

You might try ***affable*** or ***gregarious***, though five dollar words on a resume or cover-letter tend to have the opposite of the intended effect.

Though if you're truly affable, I'm sure you could recover the lost ground during the interview process :)

Comment: Do you really consider 'affable' or 'gregarious' to be five-dollar words? If that's a general perception, then our education systems are truly useless.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't call affable and gregarious five-dollar words. Seventy-five cents maybe, but not five bucks. Unlike commenter @ErikKowal, however, I would not bemoan our educational system in this country if I were to find out that 90 percent of high-schoolers did not know what the words meant.

Comment: @rhetorician - Fair enough, if we're just talking about high school students. But what if 90% of adults (e.g. interviewers) also don't know those words?

Comment: @ErikKowal: OK. Most adults should know those words. By the same token, however, I'd recommend these same folks use the words "friendly" or "easy-going" in mixed company. Not everyone need be a sesquipedalian. For a semi-interesting video on how big words can make ya look stupid, check this out: http://socialtriggers.com/the-big-problem-with-big-words-hint-they-make-you-look-stupid/  Don

Answer (score 2):

How about: [knowledgeable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=knowledgeable) at conversations; (adjective)
intelligent and well informed.

Synonyms:   well informed, learned, well read.

Answer (score 1):

**Conversationalist**

> One given to or skilled at conversation.

But you would still have to wrap it up with something

Comment: It's a good word, just wouldn't work in a resume.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the metaphor s/he is a **walking encyclopedia**.

Comment: But certainly not in a resume!